# html table span if the data is same

Tags: javascript, html, css, django-templates

I have a html table with duplicate data in the column as shown below

[image]

I want to dynamically merge the html table row cell if the data is same like below table

[image]

I am able to do this with giving the value number of cells to span but how can I do this dynamically

Comment: You can count the same sibling tr.td values, and put this value to the first td with rowspan :) But with this, you need to regenerate the whole table, with less td. Hmm, its not easy as its seems :D
You can remove the same siblings then, and done, no regeneration needed :)
But... changing the rowspan setting is really bugged with javascript, so maybe you need to regenerate the whole table :D

Comment: This is good to see, but in the JS class name is static(need to js code for every column),can we make it as dynamic which can work for all the columns in the table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, thanks for the interesting task. I came up with this solution http://jsfiddle.net/PhWGF/4/. Not the cleanest code but I will leave this part for you.

You can think about your table as a regular `2d array` so it all comes down to the classical nested loops. We search for a duplicate for each cell in each row of the same column, store first and last occurrence to determine the length of span later.

Note, you need to set all "roswpan" before deleting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tables</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="black">
        <caption>Table</caption>
       <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Parts</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">Shiva</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Math</td>
        <td>A</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>B</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Science</td>
        <td>A</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>B</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>C</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">Ram</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Math</td>
        <td>A</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>B</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Science</td>
        <td>A</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>B</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).