# AngularJS : values not binded in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/20096401/2542165 in my AngularJS app as a directive. This code merge consecutive cells containing the same values (with rowspan).

My table is generated with a ng-repeat, and my problem is that, inside my directive, the compared values are `"{{item.value1}}"` and `"{{item.value2}}"` instead of the real values.

In the example below, the two last lines are merged, but should not.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.items = 
 [
   {
    "value1":"value1",
    "value2":"value2",
   },
   {
    "value1":"value1",
    "value2":"value4",
   }
 ]

});
app.directive('mergeTable', [function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   
   function merge() {
    var mergeTableColIndex = attrs.mergeTableColIndex;
    var table = element;
    var rows = table.find($("tr"));
    var colsLength = $(rows[0]).find($("td")).length;
    var removeLater = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < colsLength; i++) {
     if(mergeTableColIndex.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
      var startIndex = 0;
      var lastIndex = 0;
      var startText = $($(rows[0]).find("td")[i]).text();
      for (var j = 1; j < rows.length; j++) {
       var cRow = $(rows[j]);
       var cCol = $(cRow.find("td")[i]);
       var currentText = cCol.text();
       if (currentText == startText) {
        removeLater.push(cCol);
        lastIndex = j;
       } else {
        var spanLength = lastIndex - startIndex;
        if (spanLength >= 1) {
         $($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]).attr("rowspan", spanLength + 1);
        }
        lastIndex = j;
        startIndex = j;
        startText = currentText;
       }
 
      }
      spanLength = lastIndex - startIndex;
      if (spanLength >= 1) {
       $($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]).attr("rowspan",
         spanLength + 1);
      }
     }
    }
    
    for(i in removeLater){
     $(removeLater[i]).remove();
    }
   }
   
    scope.$watch(attrs.mergeTable, function(value) {
     merge();
    });
  }
 };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
      <table border="1" merge-table-col-index='[0,1,2]' merge-table='items'>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
          <td>{{item.value1}}</td>
          <td>{{item.value2}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to wait for angular to render before calling merge(), using $evalAsync :

```
     scope.$watch(attrs.mergeTable, function(value) {
        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
            merge();
        });
     });
```